# Compare regression coefficients within one sample

Tags: regression, spss, regression-coefficients

I run two univariate linear regressions within one sample (same subjects, two different conditions). Now I would like to know how to compare the regression coefficients in order to find out whether they differ significantly. All of the methods I find apply to a case with two different independent samples. How do I do this in SPSS?

Comment: What would it mean for the coefficients to differ significantly? Eg, if you were looking at something as a function of height & weight, what would it mean for the coefficient on weight to be bigger than the coefficient on height?

Comment: Yes, it would be helpful if you could make the question more concrete.  Is it like you are regressing weight on height before a diet starts and then weight on height after a diet is over --- but on the same set of dieters?

Comment: Yes, it is like that, it's repeated measures. I have a sample of subjects and I look how the pre-stimulus response predict the post-stimulus response in two different conditions. so basically I'd like to know whether the preparatory response predicts the post-stimulus significantly stronger in one condition as compared to the other. I hope it's understandable.